# PageSpeed API - Batching in Java

Tags: java, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm using the PageSpeed API in my Java application. It is working fine, but since I need to check a lot of URLs I would need to do some batching. I've been looking online and in their documentation but I can't find anything on how to do it.
Does anyone know?

I am connecting with a normal HTTP Request because it turned out to be faster than using their package, but I assume for batching maybe their package is better, so here is the code I use for both scenarios:

HTTP Request:

```java
String call = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + SITE + "&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY + "&strategy=" + DEVICE;

URL url = new URL(call);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response.toString());
```

PageSpeed Java Package:

```java
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
        httpRequest.setReadTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds
    }
};

Pagespeedonline p = new Pagespeedonline.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, httpRequestInitializer).setApplicationName("APP_NAME").build();
Pagespeedonline.Pagespeedapi.Runpagespeed runpagespeed = p.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(SITE).setKey(GOOGLE_KEY).setStrategy(DEVICE);
PagespeedApiPagespeedResponseV5 response = runpagespeed.execute();
```

Both are working fine, I just need to know how to integrate batching in any of the two.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it but I forgot to share it, here it is:

```java
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
   @Override
   public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
        httpRequest.setReadTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds
    }
};

BatchRequest batch = p.batch(httpRequestInitializer);
Pagespeedonline p = new Pagespeedonline.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, httpRequestInitializer).setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();

//Loop to add as many as you want
for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); ++i) {
    Pagespeedonline.Pagespeedapi.Runpagespeed check = p.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(urls.get(i)).setKey(GOOGLE_KEY).setStrategy(DEVICE);
    check.queue(batch, callback);
}

batch.execute();
```

And this is the callback:

```java
JsonBatchCallback<PagespeedApiPagespeedResponseV5> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<PagespeedApiPagespeedResponseV5>() {

    public void onSuccess(PagespeedApiPagespeedResponseV5 response, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
        //ON SUCCESS
    }
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
        //ON FAILURE
    }
};
```